# MVC 4 Bind multiple model asp razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I develop an application who manages formations of employees, I use MVC4 Asp.net with Razor.

In my model I have tow class (who are table in my database) formation and formateur (trainers).

In my application i can create a “formation” and I want to add a list of “formative”(trainers) but I don’t know what I must do.
I think the best solution it’s a list of checkbox, I succeeded to display my list of checkbox with a foreach but I have no idea how I get the result of selected checkbox to pass into my controller.

I saw many tutorials where use “CheckBoxList” and I tried to use too, but I use a ViewBag to populate it and they don't explain how to use it with a viewbag.

Now I test a Dual listBox with tow buttons (Add and Remove) but this doesn't work.

So, somebody can help me to find, and explain how I must do,  the good or the best solution ?

I'm sorry for my english, I'm a french girl.

One of my solutions look like this :
My controller :

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {     
        ViewBag.formateurListe = (from unFormateur in db.salarie
                                 where unFormateur.sFormateur == true
                                 select unFormateur).AsEnumerable()
.Select(m => new SelectListItem
                                 {
                                     Text = m.sNom.ToString() + " " + m.sPrenom.ToString(),
                                     Value = m.sId.ToString()
                                 }).ToList();

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(formation formation, IEnumerable<SelectList> formateurList)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.formation.Add(formation);

            foreach (var unSal in formateurList)
            {
                formateur f = new formateur();
                f.ftIdFormation = formation.fId;
                f.ftIdSalarie = (int)unSal.SelectedValue;
                db.formateur.Add(f);

            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(formation);
    }
```

In my view :

```
@model MvcAppGestionRH.Models.formation
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Formation", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            @Html.Label("Libelle")        
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fLibelle)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fLibelle)

                <label id="fFormateur">Formateur</label>                                   

                @Html.ListBox("formateurListe", ViewData["formateurListe"]  as SelectListItem[], new {Multiple = "multiple"})

                <input type="button" value="+" name="add" />
                <select name="select" size="7" >
                </select>    
 <input type="submit" value="Créer" />        
}
```

With a script :

```
  $(function () {
            $("#Add").click(function () {
                $("select").add($('fFormateurListe').selected);
            });
        });
```

Comment: It's better if you could show us your code...

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes can be tricky the first time - I googled that a long time, too.

My solution is a view model which looks like this:

It is intended for questions, where the crator can speciy items via checkboxes (e.g. a questions might have the answer "GOOD" and "BAD".

```
public class QuestionModel
{
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }

    public string QuestionText { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the selected items. Purely a helper List to display check boxes for the user
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The selected items.
    /// </value>
    [Display(Name = "Items", ResourceType = typeof(Domain.Resources.Question))]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectedItems { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the selected ids. Populated by the user, when he checks / unchecks items. Later translated into QuestionItems
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The selected ids.
    /// </value>
    public int[] SelectedIds { get; set; }
}
```

This is populated like this in the QuestionController:

```
    private async Task GetSelectedItems(QuestionModel sm, Item selectedItems)
    {
        var alreadySelected = new List<Scale>();

        if (selectedScale != null)
        {
            alreadySelected.Add(selectedScale);
        }

        var itemList = (await this.uoW.ItemRepository.Get()).OrderBy(i => i.Name);

        sm.SelectedItems = itemList.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.ScaleID.ToString(),
            Text = x.NameOfScale.GetText(),
            Selected = (from a in alreadySelected where a.ItemID == x.ItemID select x).Any()
        });
    }
```

What does this do? It gets a list of all avialable items in the database and populates the model with it. Furthermore, you can pass in a list of items, which are already selected - so you can edit an existing question and siplay all already checked Items.

And n the view I have used a DropDownList:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedItems, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedIds, Model.SelectedItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedItems, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If you want checkboxes, that looks like this(different controller, so dont be confused)

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Model.SelectedItems.Count(); i++)
        {
            var currentElem = Model.SelectedItems[i];
            //if this item is selected by the user, e.g. because he is editing the item, the item will be pre-selected
            var selected = currentElem.Selected ? "checked=\"selected\"" : string.Empty;

            // column for the questions. expected layout: list of all questions
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="checkbox" id="SelectedIds">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="@currentElem.Value" @selected name="SelectedIds">
                        @Html.Encode(currentElem.Text)
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

and finally the create() method itself:

```
    [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "QuestionText,SelectedItems, SelectedIds")] QuestionModel question)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
// I need only one Item, but if you want ore more change this line
                    if (question.SelectedIds.Count() == 1)
                    {
// better use Automapper here, this is unnecessary work
                        var newQuestion = new Question { QuestionText = question.QuestionText};

                        var ItemID = question.SelectedIds.First();

                        newQuestion.QuestionScale = await this.uoW.ItemRepository.GetRaw().Where(i => i.ItemID == ItemD).FirstAsync();

                        this.uoW.QuestionRepository.Insert(newQuestion);

                        await this.uoW.Save();

                        return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.logger.Warn("User {0} tried to insert more than one Itemin question {1}", User.Identity.Name, question.QuestionID);
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, xyz.Areas.QuestionManagement.Resources.QuestionRes.ErrorTooManyScales);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
// the SelectedItems are empty in the model - so if you have to redisplay it, repopulate it.
                    await this.GetSelectedItems(question, null);
                }

                return this.View(question);
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using a viewmodel to pass your two model in the view?

For example :

ViewModel

```
public class CreateFormationViewModel
{
    public Formation formation{ get; set; }
    public List<Formative> trainers {get;set;}

}
```

and then use this viewmodel in your view

An easy way to use this view model :

In your controller

```
public ActionResult CreateFormation()
{
   //Get your data (formation and trainer)
   CreateFormationViewModel createFormationVM = new CreateFormationViewModel();
   createFormationVM.formation = YourFormationModel;
   createFormationVM.trainers = YourtrainersModelasList;

  //bind data to the view
  return View(createFormationVM);
}
```

And in your View, you have :

```
@model [yournamespace].CreateFormationViewModel
```

Comment: No, I don't use it and I don't know how to use ... It's my first project in ASP

Comment: I've had more information, it's really like using a model, but you usually use something to map your model to your viewmodel like Automapper.

Comment: What is "YourFormationModel"and "YourtrainersModelasList" ?? I'm sorry my question is probably stupid for a developper but I'm really lost. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I think this explanation is too short, it doesn't explain anythin

Comment: C'est le model que tu as surement crée pour tes formations et ta liste de formateur

Its the model you surely create to manage your data ( list of trainer, list of training)

Comment: @Cecile.jm I would suggest you go step by step in MVC or you will be lost for sure better first google "MVC MusicStore" sample code and learn MVC first than direct jumping into the stuffs.